# How to collapse PrimeFaces center lay out as east lay out

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces layout it consist of 4 units north, east, center and west.
I have a requirement such that I need to collapse the center unit as east done I mean it has to collapse to right side. Here I don't need center unit any more but center unit is mandatory.
What am doing is I have removed the east unit and using center unit but according to my requirement I have to collapse my center unit as east unit does.

Comment: Keep the east, remove the west. use center as west layout unit. so that, you can use east for collapse.

Comment: hi neni its a good idea but i want to both east and west to be collapse

Comment: Have you tried any CSS for hiding center layoutUnit?

Comment: i have tried bu its not working as expected

Comment: I tried to use some javascript and css to hide the center layoutUnit. But, It is not possible it seems. Think about another design. Look into facelets once.

Comment: instead of collapse, you could use the resize attribute of layoutUnit.  It's not collapsing, but essentially does the same thing with more control albeit with slightly more effort.

Answer (score 1):

This may give you some idea

```
 <p:layout id="L1" widgetVar="L1" >
        <p:layoutUnit position="north">
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="east" id="east">
        </p:layoutUnit>

  </p:layout>
```

you can do this to hide `L1.layout.hide('east');` and to show `L1.layout.open('east');`